# VBA Code Skipping Results in Tabular Storage of Simulation Outputs

Tags: excel, vba, debugging, skip

**Question:**

I'm using the following VBA code to store simulation results generated by R programming software in a tabular form in specified columns. However, the code seems to skip some results while placing them in the column I've specified for storing the results. I've tried multiple approaches, but I'm unable to achieve the desired outcome.

```
Sub ExtractStudentMarks()
' Define variables
Dim studentName As String
Dim studentMarks As Range
Dim examNumber As Integer

' Start from row 2 to skip headers
For i = 2 To 100
    
    ' Check if student name is one of the four
    studentName = Range("B" & i).Value
    
    Select Case studentName
        Case "MLE"
            ' Calculate exam number (integer division by 4, rounded up)
            examNumber = Int((i - 1) / 3) + 1
            ' Write student name to column I
            Range("I" & examNumber).Value = studentName
            ' Write marks to columns J, K, and L
            Range("J" & examNumber).Resize(1, 4).Value = Range("C" & i & ":F" & i).Value
        Case "mh_se_ES(MSE)"
            ' Calculate exam number (integer division by 4, rounded up)
            examNumber = Int((i - 2) / 3) + 1
            ' Write student name to column I
            Range("I" & examNumber).Value = studentName
            ' Write marks to columns J, K, and L
            Range("J" & examNumber).Resize(1, 4).Value = Range("C" & i & ":F" & i).Value
        Case "mh_bse_ES(MSE)"
            ' Calculate exam number
            examNumber = Int((i - 3) / 3) + 1 ' Adjust offset for Cq and Dq
            ' Write student name to column I
            Range("I" & examNumber).Value = studentName
            ' Write marks to columns J, K, and L
            Range("J" & examNumber).Resize(1, 4).Value = Range("C" & i & ":F" & i).Value
        
        Case "mh_ln_m_ES(MSE)"
            ' Calculate exam number
            examNumber = Int((i - 1) / 4) + 1
            ' Write student name to column O
            Range("P" & examNumber).Value = studentName
            ' Write marks to columns P, Q, and R
            Range("Q" & examNumber).Resize(1, 4).Value = Range("C" & i & ":F" & i).Value
        Case "mh_ge_m_ES(MSE)"
            ' Calculate exam number
            examNumber = Int((i - 2) / 4) + 1 ' Adjust offset for Cq and Dq
            ' Write student name to column O
            Range("P" & examNumber).Value = studentName
            ' Write marks to columns P, Q, and R
            Range("Q" & examNumber).Resize(1, 4).Value = Range("C" & i & ":F" & i).Value
        Case "mh_bln_m_ES(MSE)"
            ' Calculate exam number
            examNumber = Int((i - 3) / 4) + 1
            ' Write student name to column O
            Range("P" & examNumber).Value = studentName
            ' Write marks to columns P, Q, and R
            Range("Q" & examNumber).Resize(1, 4).Value = Range("C" & i & ":F" & i).Value
        Case "mh_bge_m_ES(MSE)"
            ' Calculate exam number
            examNumber = Int((i - 4) / 4) + 1 ' Adjust offset for Cq and Dq
            ' Write student name to column O
            Range("P" & examNumber).Value = studentName
            ' Write marks to columns P, Q, and R
            Range("Q" & examNumber).Resize(1, 4).Value = Range("C" & i & ":F" & i).Value
        
        Case "mh_ln_p_ES(MSE)"
            ' Calculate exam number
            examNumber = Int((i - 1) / 4) + 1
            ' Write student name to column O
            Range("V" & examNumber).Value = studentName
            ' Write marks to columns P, Q, and R
            Range("W" & examNumber).Resize(1, 4).Value = Range("C" & i & ":F" & i).Value
        Case "mh_ge_p_ES(MSE)"
            ' Calculate exam number
            examNumber = Int((i - 2) / 4) + 1 ' Adjust offset for Cq and Dq
            ' Write student name to column O
            Range("V" & examNumber).Value = studentName
            ' Write marks to columns P, Q, and R
            Range("W" & examNumber).Resize(1, 4).Value = Range("C" & i & ":F" & i).Value
        Case "mh_bln_p_ES(MSE)"
            ' Calculate exam number
            examNumber = Int((i - 3) / 4) + 1
            ' Write student name to column O
            Range("V" & examNumber).Value = studentName
            ' Write marks to columns P, Q, and R
            Range("W" & examNumber).Resize(1, 4).Value = Range("C" & i & ":F" & i).Value
        Case "mh_bge_p_ES(MSE)"
            ' Calculate exam number
            examNumber = Int((i - 4) / 4) + 1 ' Adjust offset for Cq and Dq
            ' Write student name to column O
            Range("V" & examNumber).Value = studentName
            ' Write marks to columns P, Q, and R
            Range("W" & examNumber).Resize(1, 4).Value = Range("C" & i & ":F" & i).Value       
        Case Else
            ' Handle unexpected student names (optional)
            Debug.Print "Unknown student name:" & studentName
    End Select   
Next i
End Sub
```

The code is supposed to write the student name to specific columns based on prefixes and store their marks in adjacent columns. However, it appears to miss some results.

Can someone please review my code and provide guidance on why it might be skipping results and how to correct it?

[This Image shows original data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2w7TK.png)

[These are resulting outputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQy98.png)

(*I'm new to VBA*)

Comment: Is `"mh_se_ES(MSE)"` really a student name or do you want to call a function named `mh_se_ES` (with parameter `MSE`)? Have you tried to debug your code by stepping thru it (use F8) and check where it behaves different as you expect? As no one has your data, it is hard to tell what exactly fails.

Comment: Thanks sir for your time.  "mh_se_ES(MSE)" is just name assigned to a function.  Besides, I've attached screenshots of my data for  clarity.

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)